# move_upload_file does not create file

Tags: php

I am writing a simple script that allows me to upload a file to a directory. To this end I use the following code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "uploading successful";    
}    
else    
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

The strange thing is that if a file `$target_path` already exists, then the upload works successfully and the original file is overwritten. However, if the file does not exist, then I get the error message that is in the else clause. Any ideas what may be the reason?

Comment: How your $target_path look like? Does it change with every request? If yes, make sure the destination directory/path exists. Also enable error reporting to see what is going on.

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to move?

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder permission if it's writable.

chmod the directory to 777

Comment: i guess this should be in comments rather than an answer

Comment: Yes it is.... I guess otherwise I could also not overwrite the file that already exists in the directory, right?

Comment: I tried chmod the director, but it does not help. Also, the directory is already on 777 and the problem happens only when the directory does not contain a file. As soon as it contains a file, everything is fine.

Comment: i think it's a directory ownership thing. delete the folder and put this in your script
// make directory
if (!is_dir($foldersPath)) {
    mkdir($foldersPath, 0755);
}

Comment: Hmmm... I don't want to delete the directory. I don't understand why it shall be an ownership problem, since when I move a file it works perfectly fine.

Comment: 777 99% of the time is never the answer